# Error of Glide library: You cannot start a load from a destroyed Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-glide

I'm using **Recycle Adapter class** and using this to populate the fragments with blog image and description. But when I **close the** **BlogActivity and move to Next Activity** then sometimes suddenly app get crashed with error of

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:You cannot start a load for a destryoed activity at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.asseertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriver.java:312)`

My Recycle adapter classs code is

```
package com.nepalpolice.cdp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;
import static com.nepalpolice.cdp.webfaq.isNetworkStatusAvialable;

public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    public Context context;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private PopupWindow popWindow;

    public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list){

        this.blog_list = blog_list;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final String blogPostId = blog_list.get(position).BlogPostId;
        final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
        holder.setDescText(desc_data);

        String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
        String thumbUri = blog_list.get(position).getImage_thumb();
        holder.setBlogImage(image_url, thumbUri);

        String user_id = blog_list.get(position).getUser_id();
        //User Data will be retrieved here...



        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String userName = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String userImage = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    holder.setUserData(userName, userImage);


                } else {

                    //Firebase Exception

                }

            }
        });

        try {
            long millisecond = blog_list.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
            String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
            holder.setTime(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //Get Likes Count
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context),new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

               if (e!=null) {
                   Log.w(TAG, "listening failed",e);
                   return;
               }

                if(!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                    int count = documentSnapshots.size();

                    holder.updateLikesCount(count);

                } else {

                    holder.updateLikesCount(0);

                }

            }
        });


        //Get Likes
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).addSnapshotListener(((Main2Activity) context),new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (e!=null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "listening failed",e);
                    return;
                }

                if (documentSnapshot.exists()){

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_accent));
                    }
                } else {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                    }else{
                        holder.blogLikeBtn.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.action_like_gray));
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        //Likes Feature
        holder.blogLikeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                        if(!task.getResult().exists()){

                            Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                            likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);

                        } else {

                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        holder.blogCommentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent commentIntent = new Intent(context, CommentsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(commentIntent);

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blog_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;

        private TextView descView;
        private ImageView blogImageView;
        private TextView blogDate;

        private TextView blogUserName;
        private CircleImageView blogUserImage;

        private ImageView blogLikeBtn;
        private TextView blogLikeCount;

        private ImageView blogCommentBtn;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            blogLikeBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
            blogCommentBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_comment_icon);

        }

        public void setDescText(String descText){

            descView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_desc);
            descView.setText(descText);

        }

        public void setBlogImage(String downloadUri, String thumbUri){

            blogImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_image);

            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder);

            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(downloadUri).thumbnail(
                    Glide.with(context).load(thumbUri)
            ).into(blogImageView);

        }

        public void setTime(String date) {

            blogDate = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_date);
            blogDate.setText(date);

        }

        public void setUserData(String name, String image){

            blogUserImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);
            blogUserName = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);

            blogUserName.setText(name);

            RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
            placeholderOption.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);

            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderOption).load(image).into(blogUserImage);

        }

        public void updateLikesCount(int count){

            blogLikeCount = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_count);
            blogLikeCount.setText(count + " Likes");

        }

    }

}
```

and my MainActivity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mainToolbar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    private String current_user_id;

    private FloatingActionButton addPostBtn;

    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView mainbottomNav;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Central Department of Physics");
        mainToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newPostIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newPostIntent);

            }
        });
        mainbottomNav = findViewById(R.id.mainBottomNav);

        // FRAGMENTS

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        replaceFragment(homeFragment);

        mainbottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.bottom_action_home :
                        replaceFragment(homeFragment);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.bottom_action_account:

                        return true;

                    case R.id.bottom_action_notif:

                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;


                }
            }
        });


        addPostBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_post_btn);
        addPostBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent newPostIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, NewPostActivity.class);
                startActivity(newPostIntent);

            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null){

            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            finish();


        } else {

            current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(current_user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        if(!task.getResult().exists()){

                            Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                            startActivity(setupIntent);
                            finish();

                        }

                    } else {

                        String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Error : " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }

                }
            });

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_logout_btn:
                logOut();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_settings_btn:

                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);

                return true;


            default:
                return false;


        }

    }

    private void logOut() {


        mAuth.signOut();
        sendToLogin();
    }

    private void sendToLogin() {

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();

    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

}
```

Here is the complete code https://github.com/akshayejh/PhotoBlog-Android-Blog-App

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check whether your activity is finishing before using Glide. Something like this:

```
if (!activity.isFinishing()) {
    Glide.with(...
}
```

Comment: I edited my code and added my mainactivity too...I think  my mainactivity doesn't incIude , what you have asked me..How can I add one??

Comment: in this case, the context in Glide.with(context) can be casted to Activity. Hence, the code should be:

if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
    Glide.with(...
}

Comment: and where should I add this in mainactivity or Recycleadapter and there are two Glide, should I add on both in adapter class...could you please post the code...it'd be a really really helpful. I almost finished my app.....Only I'm left with this bug....!!

Comment: add to all places where you use Glide

Comment: should  I add this?? if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(downloadUri).thumbnail(
                        Glide.with(context).load(thumbUri)
                ).into(blogImageView);
            }

Comment: and if I would like to show a Toast message in recyce adapter class..How can I do that??

Comment: Didn't work for me. I solved the issue by putting the Glide.with(... block in a try-catch.                 try {
                    Glide.with(context).load(countryFlagResId)
                            .apply(requestOptions)
                            .into(holder.flag);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }